# Python command that returns location to a function

Tags: python, matlab, function, file, path

I know this sounds stupid.

I am looking for python command that returns the path to the location of a function. So like

```
command(np.reshape)
```

should give the path to the folder in which np.reshape is located. I am NOT interested in finding the main location of the entire *module* (here numpy), this has been answered repeatedly. I need the precise path to the function itself, exactly like `which` is doing it in MATLAB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`inspect.getsourcefile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcefile)

As per the documentation, inspect.getsourcefile(object)

> Return the name of the Python source file in which an object was
>   defined. This will fail with a TypeError if the object is a built-in
>   module, class, or function.

Here is what I get when tested with join function:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> from os.path import join
>>> inspect.getsourcefile(join)
'C:\\Users\\ankit\\...\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\ntpath.py'
```

Comment: I think getsourcefile() is redundant to getfile()

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I was looking for. Weirdly enough, it wasn't reported here before in that clarity.

Comment: @dopexxx there is a subtle difference between the two. `getfile()` will return file path of the binary if the corresponding source file does not exist and won't complain. `getsourcefile()` on the other hand will always return the path of the source file only and raise an error if it can not find one.